# What StackExchange site manages consumer product questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Many consumer products exist in today's society, but there is not a central repository to store questions and answers related to consumer products.  It's often specific to the manufacturer or distributor, so there is a lot of biased opinions to increase sales.  Many conversations get started on various forums, but those are scattered throughout the Internet.

Is there a StackExchange site that manages these types of questions, so that experts of those products can answer those questions?

Comment: What types of consumer products do you mean?

Comment: In my specific situation, durable medical equipment (DME).  They are very expensive, and once you sign for a medical device, you usually cannot return them.  Many companies won't let you demo a product if it's not at a medical provider, so you get very little time to try it out.  Thus, an insurance company will not pay for a replacement for sometimes up to 3-5 years.

Comment: You could always propose a site, but I'm not sure what the format of the questions/answers would be.  Troubleshooting or reviews?  If it's the latter, that really wouldn't be a good fit for SE.  There has been at least one attempt to make a "consumer electronics" site and it didn't take off.  Slightly different subject matter than what you are looking for, but I could see a medical devices site meeting a similar fate.

Comment: That is a hard situation to deal with, though, so I feel for you.

Comment: How are new StackExchange sites proposed?

Comment: [A51] is the site on which you can propose a new one.  Choose an appropriate category for it (on the left) and scroll to the bottom to start a new proposal.